# Formatting SSL certificates from console output?

Tags: unix, format, ssl-certificate, ascii

I have PEM files for a MySQL instance (note the example is changed for security)
They are outputted into a JSON string which is on the console.

The PEM files have been escaped with their ASCII representations of newlines etc.

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDfzCCAmegAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB3MS0wKwYDVQQuEyQwMjI2\nNmQ5OC1jNmI2LTQxZGMtYTVmNi03OWJiNjMxOWMxYTQxIzAhBgNVBAMTGkdvb2ds\nZSBDbG91ZCBTUUwgU2VydmVyIENBMRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUsIEluYzELMAkG\nA1UEBhMCVVMwHhcNMTkwMzI5MTQwNDEwWhcNMjkwMzI2MTQwNTEwWjB3MS0wKwYD\nVQQuEyQwMjI2NmQ5OC1jNmI2LTQxZGMtYTVmNi03OWJiNjMxOWMxYTQxIzAhBgNV\nBAMTGkdvasdasdasdasdasdasdas6x15Ls6ntW9qhPy18vOsO81Dn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\nPV/K/x7dz9sEoM+agSc9V7pCzcB8A/ImxFmOkqzCnIYkN5c=\n-----END
>   CERTIFICATE-----

In this format the file is invalid when using SSL, what is the best way to format this text using vim or another suitable unix tool.

So that the result is something like this:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jq -r '.json_path.to.your.private_key' your_json_file
```

jq is available in all major distros https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/